# How to destroy and randomly generate pipes of different size?

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

So this is the code which I use to generate the pipe thingies, but after it generates it I want to destroy it after its out of screen or any other possible way, maybe after 3 seconds or any way possible and I want this pipe thingies to generate randomly in different sizes you get me ryt just like flappy bird.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Generate : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject lightnest;
    public float initialDelay;
    public float finalDelay;
    public float rampDuration;

    protected float _delay;
    protected float _runTime;
    protected float _timeSinceSpawn;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _delay = initialDelay;
        _runTime = _timeSinceSpawn = 0.0f;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        _runTime += Time.deltaTime;
        _timeSinceSpawn += Time.deltaTime;
        _delay = Mathf.Lerp(initialDelay, finalDelay, _timeSinceSpawn / rampDuration);
        if (_timeSinceSpawn > _delay) Spawn();

    }
    protected void Spawn()
    {
        _timeSinceSpawn = 0.0f;
        Instantiate(lightnest);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gameobject.transform.localScale to change the size on Start. And use gameobject.transform.position to check if the object is out of the screen. And use Destroy(gameobject) to destroy the object.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: yaa i thought of that too but do u there is any other way

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to watch this [tutorial](http://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling).

Object pooling is the most efficient way handle this kind of situtation.